# Using Express' route paths to match `/` and `/index`

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express, path

I'm using Express and I want to match `/` and `/index` to the same route. But if I write

```
app.route('/(index)?')
```

Node throws this error:

```
c:\myproject\node_modules\express\node_modules\path-to-regexp\index.js:69
  return new RegExp(path, flags);
         ^
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/(?(?:([^\/]+?)))?e\/?$/: Invalid group
    at new RegExp (native)
    at pathtoRegexp (c:\myproject\node_modules\express\node_modules\path-to-regexp\index.js:69:10)
    at new Layer (c:\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:32:17)
    at Function.proto.route (c:\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:482:15)
    at EventEmitter.app.route (c:\myproject\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:252:23)
    at c:\myproject\server.js:28:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\myproject\server.js:27:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Note that if I use

```
app.route('/foo(bar)?')
```

It works fine...

Comment: Where you include this `/^\/(?(?:([^\/]+?)))?e\/?$/` regex?

Comment: I did not. This is part of Express I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question mark is for optional route parameters, not optional route segments. For example:

```
app.route('/:myVar?');
```

With `app.route('/(index)?');` you are matching routes that are literally `"http://myapp.com/(index)"`.

You want a regular expression route.

```
app.route(/^\/(index)?$/);
```

- `^` - matches the beginning of a line, so that the whole expression must match from the beginning.
- `\/` - is an escaped forward slash, which all express route handlers usually start with.
- `(index)?` - now works as you expect because it's a regular expression. The contents of the parenthesis are optional because of the question mark.
- `$` - matches the end of a line, so that the whole expression must match all the way to the end.

If you omit `^` and `$` then the regular expression engine will try to match your expression against substrings of your route which is a bit more expensive than checking if the entire url string matches, and it could lead to route matches you didn't necessarily expect. Thanks to @robertkelp for the suggestion.

Comment: I would suggest using `/^\/(index)?$/` so it doesn't perform a substring match.